# how to solve a Problem with fastlane on Xcode with M1?

Tags: xcode, fastlane

Hello when I try to build or run my iOS app on a emulator device on Mac m1 I have this issue with fastlane on Xcode.

```
31mWARNING: fastlane requires your locale to be set to UTF-8. To learn more go to https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#set-up-environment-variables[0m
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb:43:in `match?': [31m[!] invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII[0m (ArgumentError)
```

When I go to the pathname.rb:43 I see this code but I don't what is wrong

```
def chop_basename(path) # :nodoc:
base = File.basename(path)
if /\A#{SEPARATOR_PAT}?\z/o.match?(base)
  return nil
else
  return path[0, path.rindex(base)], base
end
```

end

I have my terminal locale like this

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

How you can see all is in "en_US.UTF-8" but the Xcode show the same build error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is install fastlane with brew. When I try to install other fastlane versions with ruby, any of a version presents the same problem or another problem. But the only thing that you can do is uninstall fastlane ruby installation. and install with brew. This is the commands that I implement.

1. Uninstall Fastlane "sudo gem uninstall fastlane"
2. Verify if fastlane doesn't exist with this command "gem query --local"
3. Install with brew "brew install fastlane"

This is the version that I have:

```
Installation Source: /usr/local/Cellar/fastlane/2.207.0/libexec/bin/fastlane 
Version: 2.207.0
Xcode Version: 13.2.1
Mac OS Version: 12.2
Mac M1: Yes
```

Comment: This screws up the permissions on the Pods though. You need to delete the pods every time you run the project.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter same issue when running `fastlane` in Terminal embedded in Android Studio.

I fixed this by adding the following three variables into the shell environment:

```bash
# file .zshrc
# ...
# ...
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I use `zsh`, so the config file will be placed at ~/.zshrc by default.

Depends on what shell you used and the path of config file may be different.